# How to make mkPersist catch a typed list?

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

I've made a structure that looks like this:

```
Provider
    name String
    users [Int]
    deriving Show Generic
```

However, when migration comes in with Postgres, it automatically generates a varchar field for the users column.

Is there a way to actually make mkPersist see that it is a list of integers?

Thank you

Comment: What database type do you expect for the Haskell type `[Int]`? Persist encodes/decodes such special types as text using show/read, I think.